# How to set the default theme for users in GitLab

Tags: user-interface, gitlab

Is it possible to set the default theme for users in GitLab? Looking in the `gitlab/gitlab.yaml` I see no options to set a default.

[image]

---

Looking in the database, I see that there is a `color_scheme_id`. I'd rather not edit the database for every user.

```
    mysql> select id, name, theme_id, color_scheme_id from users;

+----+-------------------+----------+-----------------+
| id | name              | theme_id | color_scheme_id |
+----+-------------------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | Administrator     |        1 |               1 |
|  2 | foo foo           |        4 |               4 |
|  3 | bar bar           |        2 |               1 |
|  4 | foobar foobar     |        2 |               1 |
+----+-------------------+----------+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pull request in progress for that: [PR 5116](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5116), by [Izaak (John) Alpert -- (karlhungus)](https://github.com/karlhungus).

It would add to the  config/gitlab.yml.example file:

```
+    ## Default theme
+    ##   BASIC  = 1
+    ##   MARS   = 2
+    ##   MODERN = 3
+    ##   GRAY   = 4
+    ##   COLOR  = 5
+    # default_theme: 1 # default: 1
+
```

[It just got pulled a few hours ago](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5116#ref-commit-5bc07b2) (Sept. 22d), so it should be part of GitLab 6.2

---

Update August 2018, 5 years later: the current default theme is 2 (see [`gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/41db4ce1ffe4e9b07fa3e512fa399f8b3ffff63a/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L62-63).

```
### Default Theme
# gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_theme'] = 2
```